# Are there any accessories that work with a corded 1/2 inch collet DeWALT router and a cordless 1/4 inch collet DeWALT palm router?

Tags: router

I have a [DeWALT Cordless Trim Router (model DCW600B)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KSRTDML). I'm wanting to cut some dovetails for the first time with a router. I just purchased a [PORTER-CABLE Dovetail Jig with Mini Template Kit (4216)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HGL59M) to get started. Unbeknownst to me, that doesn't work for anything but "mini-dovetails" using a 1/4-inch collet router like the DCW600B I own. So I need to purchase a 1/2-inch collet router. In the DeWALT Ecosystem, that's the [2.25 HP DW618](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00006JKXB) or its smaller [1.75 HP DW616](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00006JKX9) brother.

In the DeWALT ecosystem, **are there any shared accessories that there's a good reason to *stay* with DeWALT when moving from a cordless trim router to a corded router**?

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE. This is more or less a shopping question that is at best going to attract opinion-based Answers. Which means it is not a good fit for WW.SE.

Comment: I don’t have personal experience with the dewalt router ecosystem, but it’s extremely unlikely that a palm router and a midsize router share accessories.

Comment: @jdv, uh, the OP has specifically asked about whether there are shared accessories as one means for *them* to make the call themselves. As I see it this is a perfectly reasonable feature-based query similar enough to others we've tackled numerous times previously.

Comment: It's more likely that the full-sized Bosch and DeWalt are able to share accessories more easily than the DeWalt full-sized and trim router do. Which accessories are you looking to use?

Comment: @Graphus sort of. I'd like to see an [edit] that simply asked "do the accessories from XYZ also work on ABC?" As it stands, this is very much a shopping question.

Comment: Wired/wireless vs Corded/cordless was driving me nuts. Had to change it.

Comment: I don't understand why it's opinion-based to speaking of accessories for a router and agree with @Graphus.

Comment: I think it boils down to *"So I'm wondering if there is any reason to stay with DeWALT here?"* in the context of wondering out loud about whether you should go with a Bosch instead. This does in effect ask for the opinions of others, which is why I chose to Answer the way I did :-) However I feel your pain, because there's another current Q which is directly asking for opinions which *hasn't* been closed, despite three close votes :-| @rob

Comment: @Graphus I do **not** think it in fact asks for the opinions. But as a thought experiment let's assume it does: can you help edit the question such that my answer (which is **not** an opinion but 100% objective fact sourced from Amazon's own product listings) an answer for a properly formed question which you would agree does not ask for an opinion? I don't understand your object to the wording of the question as-is, but certainly if you agree the answer provided is not an opinion we can tweak the question to salvage it?

Comment: For context, I will immediately vote to close if I think a Q is subjective and I didn't do so here. I think this is borderline, not a clear-cut example (asking straight out for opinions) and as such I didn't vote to close as you can see; and we have *many* borderline Qs here where members debated whether they should be closed and they never were. Anyhoo, I'll see if I can come up with an edit that directly feeds into your Answer. If I can't I suggest you @ rob with the same request; he has edited Qs numerous times to tweak the wording so that they can remain open.

Comment: OK so I've done a fairly drastic edit, removing the wondering about whether to move up to a Bosch instead and your Answer now directly answers that query. I expect this will be sufficient to reopen and I've cast my vote to that effect :-)

Comment: @Graphus Awesome and thanks. I welcome drastic edits. Anything to salvage the question is better than closing it 100% of the time.

Comment: "are there enough" is still subjective to me. How many is "enough". Is one sufficient? Does it need to be a simple majority (50% + 1) to be "enough"? Frankly, there are a _lot_ of "generic" router accessories (like base plates) that will fit a wide variety of brands/models. How about being specific about _which_ accessories you're interested in sharing, then just go to the DeWalt site to see if they'll fit both tools you're interested in owning. Or, just bite the bullet, since you seem to want the Bosch and get it. Anything that doesn't fit, you'll just have to buy new.

Comment: The latest edits look great for making the question less opinion-based and pushing this question further from being a shopping question. Thanks to everyone and especially @Graphus!

Comment: Also keep in mind that some accessories which are compatible with both sizes of DeWalt routers may also be compatible with other brands of routers. (Or the inverse--other brands' accessories may also be compatible with DeWalt routers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked DeWALT and they have this question in their FAQ, [*"What accessories are available for the DEWALT DCW600 Cordless Compact Router?"*](https://support.dewalt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012644498-What-accessories-are-available-for-the-DEWALT-DCW600-Cordless-Compact-Router-). This question is relatively new. DeWALT answered with the following (which I attempted to exhaustively audit),

- [DNP612 Plunge Base](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004AJ95DA) Does not seem to work on non-compact.
- [DNP615 Dust](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004AJEUKS) Does not seem to work on non-compact.
- [DW6913 (Router Edge Guide, Fine Adjustment, Vacuum Adapter)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002232W) **FITS BOTH**
- **No idea what they're talking about** <s>Edge Guide Collection Adapter For DNP612</s>
- **Duplicate** <s>Plunge Base For DNP612</s>
- **No idea what they're talking about** <s>Plunge Base DNP617</s>
- [Centering Cone (which seems to be DNP617)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004AJEUOY): **Fits 1/2 and 1/4 inch collet**
- [DNP613 Round (base plate)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004AJ95DK)
- **No idea what they're talking about** <s>DNP617 Dust</s>
- [DNP618](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09DY19ZXV) Does not seem to work on non-compact.
- **No idea what they're talking about** <s>Edge Guide Sub Base Collection Adapter For Compact Router</s>
- **No idea what they're talking about** <s>Fixed Base For Compact Router</s>
- **Duplicate of above?** <s>Fixed Base</s>

So it seems like the one accessory which may overlap wireless and wired as of 2022-03-13 is

- [DW6913 (Router Edge Guide, Fine Adjustment, Vacuum Adapter)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002232W) **FITS BOTH**

Answer (score 2):

> Do they share any accessories?

I can't answer this part but while it's certainly one way to decide on what to get even if they do I don't think it should drive the final decision.

I think the way to approach a purchase like this is to honestly assess how much future use the 1/2"-collet router is going to see *in your workshop* given you already own a trim router — so many workshop duties are well covered by trim routers, and cordless ones add an extra layer of handiness that's undeniable once you see them being used.

This isn't to decide *whether* you want/need a router that can take 1/2" bits, that need is already there, but to help decide how far up the food chain you need go in the larger router you select. If the price differential is significant enough for you to be asking I suggest a realistic assessment of how much use the larger router will get is called for.

Some people say it's always wise to buy the best you can afford, essentially "buy once, cry once", and there is obviously something to that, in both hand and power tools. But the reality is that it has never been *the* route to best value, much less the assurance of quality it is claimed to be. And the falling standards of almost all power tool brands over recent decades has further chipped away at this argument -_-

So in recent years there has been a rise in the "buy cheap/cheaper, see how much I actually use it" camp. This has a few advantages you can probably think of yourself, but sometimes there's a pleasant surprise in store when you discover just how good a tool is even though it's one or even a couple of rungs down the ladder!

Comment: If the query were boiled down to "Is one of the Bosch routers worth it to me?" for me the decision was easy. I went with a router from an off brand that fairly consistently got good reviews which cost less than a third of what the (roughly) equivalent Bosch router would have cost me at the time. And that price differential has increased *noticeably* since then.

Comment: I'm not advocating festool, but dovetails on a jig require a router that is going to stay adjusted very precisely. I sincerely doubt that a harbor freight or even a basic craftsman is going to do the trick. OTOH, Porter Cable 690 routers (the 1-1/2hp workhorse) come up on my local craigslist very regularly... I've bought for as low as $50. (Don't buy anything that grinds or whines or is rusty or has obviously loose bearings. Get wrenches and at least the 1/2" collet you need. Accessorizing something that's lost all its parts gets expensive quick.)

Comment: I upvoted but this wasn't the answer I was looking for. ;) thanks for trying though. I self-answered it too.

Comment: Well done on the self-answer, I upvoted.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, well FWIW the sub-30 dollar router I refer to in the Comment holds settings just fine. Which adjustments are you thinking a lower-priced router *can't* be trusted to keep? Given the OP's initial requirement to use it in a dovetail jig I'd expect ANY router that can take a suitable bit to be up to the task, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @graphus — it sounds like you found a sweet spot, price/performance-wise. I stand by my caution about tools that are too cheaply made to hold alignment (both plain old height and position of cutter in the collet).

Comment: This, more or less. Though I will add that once you invest in cordless tools I suggest sticking with that colour for cordless tools. Part of this hobby is getting better at guessing _when_ it is ok to bargain shop -- essentially experimenting with the point of diminishing returns. I might buy a good enough hardpoint (disposable) hand saw, but I will never pay less than eye-watering for tooling like drill or router bits, or saw blades. This is something both personal and 100% experience.